# How can I pass a child component ViewContainerRef to a global configuration provider in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Angular Material allows you to specify [global defaults for the SnackBar component](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview#setting-the-global-configuration-defaults) by passing the options to a Module's `providers`:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {provide: MAT_SNACK_BAR_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: {duration: 2500}}
  ]
})
```

I'd like to specify that the default `ViewContainerRef` option is a component a few levels down the tree in my app -- I have a sidebar, plus a bit of top and bottom decoration, and I'd like the Snackbar to appear relative to the main content inside all this stuff.  I just don't know how to get a ref to a component "down there" in the context of top-level module declaration.

Is there a standard pattern to use here?  Obviously there's a kind of race condition, where the value at the module-level can't be defined until the child (descendant, really) has actually been initialized, but that's fine -- the VCR option could just be left at the default then changed when it's ready.  I have a few vague ideas how this could work, but I don't think I'm supposed to create circular references between the module and the target component.

Comment: Sorry about my answer @Coderer I was keeping that question opened because it's interesting and wanted to reply to another one... Got confused and post the wrong one here. Deleted it.

Comment: Ah, whew, I thought I had badly pooched the question.  I think if I dig deep enough I'm probably asking if I can change a provider (or a property of a provider) used by the injection service at runtime, and the well-established answer to that is "no".  I'm going to keep playing with it, though.